# Show Image inside a progress bar step

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show the progress bar.

I have uploaded the file here - https://jsfiddle.net/iftekhar09/7ojsz5qp/1/
Also there's a snippet below.

I want to put the Image (say from font-awesome) in place of the number "1", how can I achieve this?

[image]

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
}
.task-progress-header{
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.progressbar li img{
  width: 15px;
}

.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}
.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 14%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<div class="task-progress-header">Your Progress</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
<!--    <li><img src="../../../assets/calendar.svg"><br></li>-->
    <li class="active"><a href=""></a>Create Event</li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Setup Exhibitors</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Setup Sponsors</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Add participants</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Setup Questions</a></li>
    <li>Done</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem? You can read how to use font awesome at their official site

Comment: I want to put an Image in place of the number "1" , "2" , "3"

Comment: yeah, i understand. So what have you tried and what trouble have you encountered?

Comment: I tried to do <li><img src="../../../assets/calendar.svg"><br></li> (as shown in the code above) but the image is showing below the circle and not inside it

Comment: How are these numbers 1,2,3 are placed inside circle? I think you can put images the same way these numbers put in

Comment: in the css selector .progressbar li:before the content is added via counter content: **counter(step);** and increments with the follow rule **counter-increment: step;** you can add fontawesome icons instead of bullets in an ordered or unorderedlist. [Check out the documentation for that](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list)
But you'll have to rewrite part of the css to get the icon on the correct place instead of the number than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `content:''` `background:url` inside `.progressbar li:before` class and give the image URL it works.
I hope this is what you are expecting

For different images at each step:

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
}

.task-progress-header {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.progressbar li img {
  width: 15px;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 14%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(1):before {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/30x0/c0c/fff);
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(2):before {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/30x0/00c/fff);
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(3):before {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/30x0/c0/fff);
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(4):before {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/30x0/0fc/fff);
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(5):before {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/30x0/f0c/fff);
}

.progressbar li:nth-child(6):before {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/30x0/002/fff);
}

.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: '';
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.active+li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<div class="task-progress-header">Your Progress</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <!--    <li><img src="../../../assets/calendar.svg"><br></li>-->
    <li class="active">
      <a href=""></a>Create Event</li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Setup Exhibitors</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Setup Sponsors</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Add participants</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Setup Questions</a></li>
    <li>Done</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Same image at each step:

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
}

.task-progress-header {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.progressbar li img {
  width: 15px;
}

.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 14%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7d7d7d;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/30x0/002/fff);
}

.progressbar li:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  content: '';
  line-height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #7d7d7d;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

.progressbar li:after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content: none;
}

.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}

.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #55b776;
}

.progressbar li.active+li:after {
  background-color: #55b776;
}
```

```html
<div class="task-progress-header">Your Progress</div>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <!--    <li><img src="../../../assets/calendar.svg"><br></li>-->
    <li class="active">
      <a href=""></a>Create Event</li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Setup Exhibitors</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="">Setup Sponsors</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Add participants</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Setup Questions</a></li>
    <li>Done</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I think he wants seperate images for each step ;)

Answer (score 1):

I made my own progress step bar.
Maybe this will come to use for someone.
In this progress step bar every step has its own image.

```css
.bs-wizard {margin-top: 20px;}
                       
.bs-wizard {border-bottom: solid 1px #e0e0e0; padding: 0 0 10px 0;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step {padding: 0; position: relative; width: 16.5% !important;}
.stepvijf > .bs-wizard-step {padding: 0; position: relative; width: 20% !important;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step + .bs-wizard-step {}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-stepnum {color: #333; font-size: 16px; margin-bottom: 5px;}

.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .bs-wizard-dot {position: absolute; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: block; background: #84b826; top: 45px; left: 50%; margin-top: -15px; margin-left: -15px; border-radius: 50%;} 
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .progress {position: relative; border-radius: 0px; height: 8px; box-shadow: none; margin: 20px 0; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-top: 1px solid;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step > .progress > .progress-bar {width:0px; box-shadow: none; background: #84b826;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.complete > .progress > .progress-bar {width:100%;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.active > .progress > .progress-bar {width:50%;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:first-child.active > .progress > .progress-bar {width:0%;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:last-child.active > .progress > .progress-bar {width: 100%;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.disabled > .bs-wizard-dot {background-color: #f5f7f8;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.disabled > .bs-wizard-dot:after {opacity: 0;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:first-child  > .progress {left: 50%; width: 50%;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step:last-child  > .progress {width: 50%;}
.bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step.disabled a.bs-wizard-dot{ pointer-events: none; }


    @media all and (max-width: 1550px) {
    .bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-info {color: #333; font-size: 10px !important;}
    }
    @media all and (min-width:1550px) {
         .bs-wizard > .bs-wizard-step .bs-wizard-info {color: #333; font-size: 14px;}
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" style="width: 105%; padding-right: 60px;">
  <div class="row bs-wizard" style="border-bottom:0;">
      <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete">
        <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 1</div>
        <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot" style=""><img src="https://tfsassets.azureedge.net/sampletry.jpg" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-top: -2px; "></a>
        <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Start order</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete"><!-- complete -->
        <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 2</div>
        <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"><img src="https://tfsassets.azureedge.net/sampletry.jpg" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-top: -2px; "></a>
        <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Payment received</div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete"><!-- complete -->
        <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 3</div>
        <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"><img src="https://tfsassets.azureedge.net/sampletry.jpg" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-top: -2px; "></a>
        <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Sorting</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete"><!-- active -->
        <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 4</div>
        <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"><img src="https://tfsassets.azureedge.net/sampletry.jpg" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-top: -2px; "></a>
        <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center"> Package underway</div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step disabled"><!-- active -->
        <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 5</div>
        <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"><img src="https://tfsassets.azureedge.net/sampletry.jpg" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-top: -2px; "></a>
        <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center"> Almost delivered</div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step disabled"><!-- active -->
        <div class="text-center bs-wizard-stepnum">Step 6</div>
        <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
        <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot"><img src="https://tfsassets.azureedge.net/sampletry.jpg" style="height: 35px; width: 35px; margin-top: -2px; "></a>
        <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center"> Delivered</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```